# Trouble viewing locally served (MAMP) Wordpress site over WiFi

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wifi, server, mamp

I'm building a site using MAMP and Wordpress on my MacBook. When I try and view it over WiFi on my Windows PC I can see the html but images and CSS files are not loading.

Does anyone know where I can begin to try and find the problem? What I might be able to do to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your WiFi routner has its own subnet. If possible, configure it as an Access Point - or  buy one. This is cheaper then working with routing tables.

Peter